# Android /data/data/mypackage/img

Tags: android, file

I have saved same image into /data/data/mypackage/img/ and now I want show this full screen, I had try with ACTION_VIEW for show with android standard program but it not read from /data/data/..
How can I do ?

Comment: You need to clarify your question, I have no idea what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'android standard program' you are launching is not able to access /data/data/mypackage, and thus cannot load the images you are saving in there

Try saving your images in a directory on the SD card instead:

```
File sdDir = new File(Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mydirname");
```

If your device doesn't have an SD card then you will need to create a world readable subdirectory inside your package dir, and then create a world readable file within it (Android 2.3+)

```
File filesysDir = getDir("mydirname", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
File file = new File(sdDir, "myfile.txt");
file.setReadable(true, false);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
String txt = "hello world";
fos.write(txt.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Or if you are on earlier versions of Android it looks like you don't get much choice in the directory name. The following code will create a world readable file in the data/data/mypackagename/files/ directory

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("myfile2.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String txt = "hello world";
fos.write(txt.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Comment: But this External Storage Directory is the microSD or the internal phone memory ?

Comment: mmm no....if the device not have the microSD ? but I can write into internal memory ?

Comment: Ok, in that case you will need to make sure your packages subdir has world read permissions on it. eg. File imgDir = getDir("img", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

Comment: Can you to do me an exemple for create a directory in internal memory with world read permissions  ? please ? :(

Comment: and you may need to also set that permission on the file itself when you create it. e.g. FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput ("myfile.jpg", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

Comment: RECORDING_FILE_NAME
protected static final String RECORDING_FILE_NAME = "/data/data/it.android.dev.miopackage/img/";
File dir_world = getDir(RECORDING_FILE_NAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
it say me IllegalArgumentException