# Unknown Chromium Error -6 when loading local images in Android Webview

Tags: android, html, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working on a Worklight project that downloads a zip file, unpacks it, and stores the files in the specific documents directory of the platform (in iOS that's `NSDocumentDirectory`, on Android I'm using `getFilesDir()`). The file consists of one HTML file and several images, located in a sub directory (media). Downloading and unzipping works fine on both platforms. After the unzip process I'm loading the contents of the HTML file into an existing div (since this is a Worklight app, everything is in one HTML file).

Here things become complicated:
The image tag sources in the HTML file that I've downloaded are relative to the HTML file (e.g. 'media/myimage.jpg'). When I inject the HTML file into the Worklight HTML file (which is located in the App bundle/package), the base URL changes and the images can't be found anywhere. I fixed this by writing native functions that rewrite all the image tags in the downloaded HTML file to point to an absolute URL (iOS: `/var/mobile/Applications/<identifier>/Documents/`, Android: `/data/data/<id>/files/`). This works fine on iOS, but on Android it causes the HTML to only load partially. LogCat then shows:

```
Unknown chromium error: -6
```

If I keep the files as they are, the HTML loads correctly, but obviously with broken images. I've also tried to change the URLs to `file:///data/data/<id>/files/ [...]`, which also causes the HTML to not load completely. I have really no idea what is causing this problem. The app already has the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [Android /data/data/mypackage/img][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408838/android-data-data-mypackage-img

Comment: @René, have you solved this?

Comment: Turns out this error was caused by having images that are larger than 1500px in width. After scaling them down, the error disappears. Must be a problem with the Android webview, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this error was caused by having images that are larger than 1500px in width. After scaling them down, the error disappears. Must be a problem with the Android webview, I guess.